# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor while saving image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i amusing PIL to write some text inside and an image and then saving it at the same location. Following is my function which does this

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

def add_text_to_image(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    widht, height = img.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("helvetica.ttf", 20)
    draw.text((0, 0), "Some text", (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    img.save(image_path)
```

But i am getting following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/background_task/tasks.py",
>
> line 43, in bg_runner func(*args, **kwargs) File
>
> "/home/paksign/app/app/document/tasks.py", line 74, in
>
> document_status_changed_to_completed
>
> add_branding_texts_to_document_images(meta) File
>
> "/home/paksign/app/app/document/utils.py", line 277, in
>
> add_branding_texts_to_document_images for snapshot in snapshots: File
>
> "/home/paksign/app/app/document/utils.py", line 270, in
>
> add_text_to_image img.save(image_path) File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1994, in
>
> save save_handler(self, fp, filename) File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line
>
> 761, in _save ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0,
>
> rawmode)], bufsize) File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 519,
>
> in _save s = e.encode_to_file(fh, bufsize) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file
>
> descriptor Marking task
>
> document.tasks.document_status_changed_to_completed as failed

i have tried some solution from internet but nothing is working and i don't know what i am doing wrong here. any help is appreciated

Comment: The code works for me, I've tested on JPEG & PNG images. The image is saved with the text "Some Text" at the top-left of the image.

Comment: Maybe file has read-only attribute or is blocked with another application (so it's read-only for your application) or you run it as a non-priviliged user (no writing permissions)

Comment: That code in and of itself doesn't do anything. Please extract a [mcve] instead.